# Trigger an event when a game object touches a non-solid game object

Tags: 2d, unity, physics

For a 2d game, I are currently making an AI and I want it to jump when it touches a invisible cube, which isn't solid, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Invisible**: Don't add any components that render to the screen, i.e. mesh renderer, sprite renderer, line renderer, etc.
- **Collidable**: Add a [physics collider](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/collider2d) to the object and set the bounds how you like.
- **Non-solid**: [Make the collider a trigger](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers). Triggers will trigger a collision event, but won't have a collision response, essentially making them non-solid objects.

Add your trigger code to the `OnTriggerEnter` method in your script. This method is called when the trigger is first touched by another game object's collider.